# Is hyphenation of …tion(s)… allowed in all cases?

Tags: hyphenation

I keep noticing more and more cases where the syllable “-tion(s)-” is split in the middle, in words like “*Informati-onsveranstaltung*”, including LaTeX text processing software and teletext of ARD television who do so.

In elementary school [in Germany!] we learned (at the end of the 80s, before any form of spelling reform) that one should separate syllables as one would “clap” words. In the above case, I feel that would be “*In-for-ma-tions-ver-an-stal-tung*”, but a syllabification in the middle of “-tion(s)-” (when pronounced *tsjons*) is wrong (where it would be okay in cases pronounced *zihohn*, like in “*Na-ti-o-nen*”).

As current way of using German (as proposed by the Conference of Ministers of Education), is a syllabification in the middle of “-tion(s)-” (when pronounced *tsjons*) correct or wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Informationsveranstaltung) permits these hyphenation positions:

> In|for|ma|ti|ons|ver|an|stal|tung

And among the strong move towards flexibility by the orthography revision, there is a new rule, according to that single vocals may be hyphenated, as long as no component boundary in compound words is affected, so *nati-onal* as well as *natio-nal* are permitted. I found only a non-authoritative source online [Focus online](https://praxistipps.focus.de/silbentrennung-regeln-und-funktionsweise-einfach-erklaert_99467). The general [Duden hyphenation page](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/worttrennung) seems not very exhaustive.

Comment: What most dictionaries ignore and most hyphenation software  doesn't even know, (and Latex with its pure algorithmic hyphenation is especially bad at this) is that not all potential places for a hyphen are equally suitable - Informations-veranstaltung would in this special case be a way better hyphenation with not much more compromise for inter-word space. Composites should preferrably be split into their original components, if at all possible.

Comment: Software will have to be told about theses preferred hyphenation points, of course, should it become relevant in your text. Conditional hyphenation exists …